# Magento EE 1.14.4.4 Upgrade - Console error on Place Order in IE

Tags: magento-ee

We have upgraded our `Magento EE 1.14.4.4`.

After upgrade, Place order functionality not working as expected in `IE 11`. When we click the Place `Order Button`, It throws a console error `review is not defined`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

made a gist to fix the error in IE11
override template:

> app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/onepage/review.phtml

with gist here:
https://gist.github.com/roman204/c5468879074826dc9b1eb20a6bc5fca4

Comment: Thank you, Rakesh. It worked perfectly. Can you give some insights about the fix and the issue?

Comment: Done. Can you give some insights about the fix and the issue?

Comment: @Agnes which issue facing? can you post as new question

Comment: I am asking about the current issue.

Answer (score 1):

Though @rakesh-donga answer has solved my issue, I faced other console errors in IE 11 Browser, which made me dig into the issue much deeper. Finally found the exact issue and fix.

We have faced some console errors and button click issues in our site after upgrading to 1.14.4.4. These errors break place order functionality, toolbar options and compare links in the PLP page.

**Console Errors:**

> 'review' is not defined
>
> 'decorateTable' is not defined
>
> 'setLocation' is not defined

In this 1.14.4.4 release, Magento fixed the button issue (button click not changing the state as expected) in **Admin->System->Compilation->Tools->Compiler** section. For this, they have added a new JS function called buttonDisabler() in

> js/varien/js.js

```
function buttonDisabler() {
  const buttons = document.querySelectorAll('button.save');
  buttons.forEach(button => button.disabled = true);
}
```

This function caused the issues in IE 11 Browser. The "<" operator used in this function is not supported in IE, which throws a syntax error and stops the next functions.

To Fix this, we have updated the function as below (replacing the "<" operator") in

> js/varien.js.js

```
function buttonDisabler() {
    const buttons = document.querySelectorAll('button.save');
    buttons.forEach(function(button) {
        button.disabled = true;
    });
}
```

Comment: js file changes worked for me. thanks